# Is it good Python practice to reuse SystemRandom?

Tags: python, random

For example, a block of Python code to generate 1 million random strings off the alphabet 'abcdef'.

Compare

```
from random import SystemRandom

for _ in range(1000000):
    ''.join(SystemRandom().choice('abcdef') for __ in range(5))
```

with

```
from random import SystemRandom

r = SystemRandom()
for _ in range(1000000):
    ''.join(r.choice('abcdef') for __ in range(5))
```

I timed it on IPython. The 1st block took 50s while the 2nd block took 30s. I didn't measure the memory usage.

In Java, there is SecureRandom where the pattern is clear that it should be created once and reused. Coming from Java to Python, it is not clear to me whether I should create a single SystemRandom instance and reuse it. The 1st block is easier to read and the performance does not seem too bad.

In general, does Python programming pay more attention to readability than performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SystemRandom` builds on the platform C's `urandom()` function, which is as secure as your operating system developers knew how to make it.  Virtually everyone uses a single instance of it (as in your second example).

There's no real conflict between performance and readability here.  Idiomatic Python would be like:

```
from random import SystemRandom
r = SystemRandom()
choice = r.choice

for _ in range(1000000):
    ''.join(choice('abcdef') for _ in range(5))
```

Comment: Is it the expense of _creating_ `SystemRandom` or the expense of _using_ it's methods?  As far as I can tell, `self.random()` is called from within `self.choice()` and `SystemRandom.random` is what calls `urandom()` -- not   `SystemRandom.__init__`.

Comment: Sure - but I don't think it's worth more words to clarify that creating things that are never used _can_ be cheap ;-)  But on third thought, all instances use the same `urandom()` platform instance, so I'll remove the bit about expense - I agree now it's at best misleading.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, I usually look at [the implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l805) ...

As far as I can tell, `SystemRandom` works pretty much exactly the same as `Random` ([which *is* reused by all of the module-level functions](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l885)) except that the `random` method is swapped out to call `os.urandom`.  So, as far as I can tell, you should be able to re-use a `SystemRandom` instance.

> In general, does Python programming pay more attention to readability than performance?

In general, I think that the mentality is that **readability counts** and **code is read more often than written**.  You should only really spend time (or code complexity) optimizing things which are taking a significant amount of your over-all program running time.  If creating and calling `SecureRandom` takes a tiny percentage of your overall program running time, then it's probably not worth optimizing and you should definitely go with the more easy to read version.  If it takes 50% of the run-time and waiting for the program to complete is annoying, you might want to look into optimizing.

Of course, with that said, I don't think there's much of a readability difference between your two code snippets, so ... I'd probably create one and reuse it...

Comment: Actually a more important question I forgot to ask is whether it is safe to reuse a single instance.  Thanks for pointing it out first.